# Compiling on Windows and Mac with Autotool

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, mingw, autotools

I have a problem trying to use autotools for a simple contrived project, the task is simple, use Objective-C on Mac OSX, and C++ on Windows (mingw) - with some `C` glue in the middle.

The project is structured like so (minus all the automatically generated files):

```
    ./aclocal.m4
    ./configure
    ./configure.ac
    ./Makefile.am
    ./src/darwin/greet.m
    ./src/greet.h
    ./src/main.cpp
    ./src/Makefile.am
    ./src/mingw32/greet.cpp
```

**The contents of the key files are here on [github in a gist](https://gist.github.com/c323cb588e1f2e90f610). (didn't want to spam here)**

I'm using the following command between changes:

```
$ autoreconf -vis && ./configure && make
```

The error I receive is full output ([here in another gist](https://gist.github.com/0198de86e4ae6b53d026)):

```
....
Making all in src
g++  -g -O2   -o greetings main.o  
Undefined symbols:
  "greet()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [greetings] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm very new to autotools, and have come a long way with the help of a couple of good people on IRC, but I think I'm making a conceptual mistake here, really hope there's a simple mistake I am making.

It was my understanding from the docs that `EXTRA_progname_SOURCES` should contain all possible files, and that the conditionals which are setup should work to select the correct ones.

Alarmingly, I don't think my makefiles are being remade, because even when I change the line in `src/Makefile.am` to include the sources explicitly for my platform (which is Max OS X Darwin, most of the time) -- the output remains completely the same.

Comment: This is linker error. Forger about autotools, just try to understand why greet function is not found. Where is it supposed to be - in some other .c/.cpp file, or in some linrary?

Comment: Alex, the function is defined in header `src/greet.h` with platform specific implementations (read: one uses Objective-C, the other C++) implementations in `src/darwin/greet.mm` and the other in `src/mingw31/greet.cpp`

Comment: If I revise my command to be `$ autoreconf -vis && ./configure && make clean && make` (note the addition of make clean) - then I see a much more interesting error: `g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"greetings\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"greetings\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"greetings\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"lee.hambley@gmail.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"greetings\" -DVERSION=\"1.0\" -I. -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o main.o main.cpp && mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po` (https://gist.github.com/f5ef9704267c7284c853)

Comment: You can see if the Makefiles are being remade by keeping an eye out for a call to `automake` in the output of `make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're referring to `greet.mm` in the gist, but `greet.m` in the question. Automake does not appear to [natively support](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Programs.html#Programs) Objective-C++ code. For Objective-C code, you need to have `AC_PROG_OBJC` in your `configure.ac`. If you really meant Objective-C++ code, you'll need to do this [via a suffix rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Suffixes.html#Suffixes).

Comment: Jack, thanks for the tip, I'll take a look into that today, if I find some time.

Comment: You were right, as soon as I fixed the `Makefile.am` to look for `.m` files, `autoreconf` warned me that I should add `AC_PROG_OBJC` to `configure.ac` - at which time the list of files passed to the compiler was complete, but left me still with linker problems which I'm working through.

Comment: @Beaks: What is your automake version (`automake --version`)?

Comment: @Jack, this is resolved (partly) now - but here's the info you asked for: `automake (GNU automake) 1.11.1` and `autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.67`

Comment: @Beaks: With an automake version that recent I can't see you having problems with `+=`. Can you open another question and provide pastebins of a full `configure;make` run?

Comment: Jack, I gave you the vote as the correct answer, because the file naming was wrong - the trouble I have now is that the linker doesn't find the symbols from the .m file (probably because they're `C++` code in a `.m` file. I'll open another question (and ping you early, if you like) with my follow-up.

Comment: @Beaks: If you do, I'll give helping out a shot. If automake is adding the file but it's not linking (as in, you see two `.o` files on the link line), you probably want to declare the functions that cross the boundary `extern "C"`. (Alternative: Use objective-C++ here?) If you're not compiling the second file _at all_, then it's some weirdness in the build tool.

Answer (score 0):

g++  -g -O2   -o greetings main.o

This line tries to build greetings executable from main.o. If greet() function is defined in some other file, for example, greet.cpp, it should be:

++  -g -O2   -o greetings main.o greet.o

Possibly, this line from Makefile.am

greetings_SOURCES = main.cpp greet.h

should be something like this:

greetings_SOURCES = main.cpp greet.cpp

In Makefile.am you have:

```
if OS_DARWIN  
greetings_SOURCES += darwin/greet.mm
endif
if OS_MINGW32  
greetings_SOURCES += mingw32/greet.cpp
endif
```

This is the place which is not executed properly. You need to check it.

Comment: Acknowledged, but I don't know enough about autotools to debug this, what can you suggest?

Comment: Try to change greetings_SOURCES unconditionally, adding required .cpp file to it. It it solves the problem, this means, that "if" or += is not executed as expected. If you are working with autotools, read this book: http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool

Comment: I just did a small test using only `.c` files: it seems to be safe to += a `foo_SOURCES` variable if everything is listed in `EXTRA_foo_SOURCES`.